# How to highlight text when click label in xamarin forms?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

How to highlight text when click label get the index position and highlight One Sentence in xamarin forms.

**This is my layout looks llike**

```
 <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Loremipsum.Content}"
                           x:Name="LoremipsumText"
                           FontSize="18"
                           FontFamily="Font4"
                           TextTransform="None"
                           TextColor="White">
                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="btnHighLight"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Label>
                </StackLayout>
```

[See this picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAWYd.png)

if the image is not load
this is the text example

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

iwant to hilght is this text

> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.

and this is my cs codes look likes

```
public partial class LoremipsumInfoPage : ContentPage
{

    string[] strList;

    public LoremipsumInfoPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        string verses = Loremipsum.Text;
        string strDot = ".";
        char charDot= char.Parse(strDot);
        string strComma = ",";
        char charComma = char.Parse(strComma);

        strList = verses.Split(new char[] { charDot, charComma });

    }


    private void btnHighLight(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var formattedString = new FormattedString();

        for (int v = 0; v < strList.Length; v++)
        {
            if (v == v)
            {
                formattedString.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = strList[v], ForegroundColor = Color.White, BackgroundColor = Color.Red });
            }
            else
            {
                formattedString.Spans.Add(new Span { Text = strList[v], ForegroundColor = Color.Black });
            }
        }
        Loremipsum.FormattedText = formattedString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the [Label's FormattedText property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.label.formattedtext?view=xamarin-forms) to a [FormattedString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.formattedstring?view=xamarin-forms), that has three [Spans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.span?view=xamarin-forms), one for the text before, one for the text to highlight (set its backgroundcolor), one for the text after.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve can you provide sample code ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to take the time to do that. Its basic stuff. Please go read those links. You could also `google` for examples. **After** reading about these features, finding examples, and experimenting with code, If you can't get it working right, then **post code that tries to do it**, and explain what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @ToolmakerSteve for answering this basic stuff sorry newbie in xamarin.

Comment: Its okay. I understand that this is new to you. Just clarifying how stackoverflow works best. If you struggle with it, and have trouble getting it right, then others in the future will probably have similar problems. Then you show your code, explain the problem, someone helps you. The advantage of this is that a) you learn to get as far as you can, and b) the result is a Q&A, based on a code problem, that will be helpful to others. The idea is to build a repository of useful knowledge. That everyone can refer to.

Comment: I forgot to mention: If you do solve it on your own, please come back and add "Your Answer" below. Then everyone will see how to do this! You will be contributing what you learned. :)

Answer (score 0):

As ToolmakerSteve said,you can set the formattedText of label with **span**.I write a sample you can refer to:

```
                 <Label>
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <Span Text="This is a text" />
                            <Span x:Name="hlText" Text="This is a highlighttext"/ >
                        </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                     <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapped" />
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
```

codebehind:

```
void OnTapped(object Sender,Eventargs e)
{hlText.color=Color.Red
}
```

Comment: Zhu Hi but my label text is binding from mvvm archeticture.

Comment: you can change the one binding text into two span text and bind with them.